# Trying to get a discord bot to pick a random user

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I am attempting to make a bot that will print a random user for my discord channel. The problem is that I keep getting weird errors while in the bot.on function. I am trying to use the code `var randomUser = message.guild.name.random();` however this returns:

```
C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:18       
        var randomUser = message.guild.name.random(); 
                                            ^

TypeError: message.guild.name.random is not a function
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guild.name` returns the name of the guild, not the collection of it's `members`. your solution is:

**v11**

```js
var randomUser = message.guild.members.random();
```

**v12**

```js
var randomUser = message.guild.members.cache.random();
```

Comment: Thanks! Cache worked. I just forgot to do members in the post also. Cheers!

Comment: Please accept the answer to let others know it worked